# active_id and actions in transientModel odoo

Tags: odoo, odoo-11, erp, odoo-view

I am trying to get some values from (hr.payslip) model. Before that I need to add one more option in Action (dropdown list) where you can delete or export selected payslip. So when I select a payslip from treeView (checkbox in the image below) that new option should show up a wizard showing a table One2many having the selected payslip so I can Print or do some other action.

This is the scenario and i did not start any coding to do that.

I am new to odoo. I hope you can help me with some example.

[image]

Comment: question is unclear, please explain clearly.

Comment: question is edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to create new action and new object also
create new object

```py
class NewObject(models.TransientModel):
    _name = 'new.object'
    _description = 'Description of new object'
    @api.multi
    def generate_report(self):
         payslip_ids = self._.get('active_ids',[])
         #payslip_ids this will be your selected payslip ids in list view.
```

```xml
<act_window 
        name="Your Action string" 
        res_model="new.object"
        src_model="hr.payslip" 
        view_mode="form" 
        view_type="form"
        target="new" 
        multi="True" 
        key2="client_action_multi"
        id="id_of_act_window"
        view_id="view of new object"        
    />
```

then create view for new object

```xml
<record id="id of new view" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">Name of view</field>
        <field name="model">model of new view</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form string="">
                <button name="generate_report" string="Generate Report
                        type="object" class="oe_highlight" />
            </form>
        </field>
    </record>
```

and here you can add your code you want like.